# Ruby request headers but also a ?tag=tag

Tags: ruby, curl, rest-client

I am trying to send an API call to consul using a ruby script and I have a command that should be close to what I need but I can't get the rest to work.

```
RestClient::Request.execute(method: :get, url: path, timeout: 10, headers: {params: {"tag": tag, "X-Consul-Token" => encode_auth_token}})
```

Pretty much I need the call to be like if I did

`curl --header "X-Consul-Token: <my token>" <my path>?tag=tag`  where the last tag in `?tag=tag` is a variable and the token is a variable too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are extremely close, right now this does not work for you because the `"X-Consul-Token" => 'AUTH_TOKEN'` is being seen as a url parameter and not a header.

```
req.url 
#=> "http://example.com?tag=tag&X-Consul-Token=AUTH_TOKEN"
req.headers 
#=> {}
```

To fix this you just need to have params and the other header tags separated:

```
req=  RestClient::Request.new(
  method: :get, 
  url: 'http://example.com/', 
  timeout: 10, 
  headers: {params: {tag: 'tag'},
           "X-Consul-Token" => 'AUTH_TOKEN'}) #notice outside of params
req.url
#=> "http://example.com?tag=tag"
req.headers 
#=> {"X-Consul-Token"=>"AUTH_TOKEN"}
```